# I don't know how to do conditional branching in data frames

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to perform conditional branching with the window function.

```
window = Window.partitionBy("row").orderBy(f.col("date").desc())
todo_code = df.withColumn("number",
  f.when(f.col('row') == 2),
  f.row_number().over(window).filter(f.col("number") <= 3))
 .otherwise(f.row_number().over(window).filter(f.col("number") <= 1))))
```

I want to create a conditional branch in the window function depending on the column of data.
Error when running

```
when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: when() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

We want to convert this kind of data into the table below .

**df**

| row | number | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | row | a |
| 2 | row | a |
| 2 | row | a |
| 1 | row | b |
| 2 | row | b |
| 2 | row | b |

**todo_code**

| row | number | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | row | b |
| 2 | row | a |
| 2 | row | a |
| 2 | row | a |

Comment: Could you show some sample data?  It's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. Why are you putting `.filter` after `row_number`? You cannot filter a row number. You can only filter a dataframe.